# Storing permanent JWT in HttpOnly + SameSite=Strict + Secure cookie?

Tags: jwt

I'm wondering what are the nowadays risks of storing a JWT that does not expire in an `HttpOnly`, `SameSite=Strict`, and `Secure` cookie.

I understand `localStorage` is vulnerable to XSS, and that normal cookies are vulnerable to CSRF, so that's why it's recommended to use temporary JWTs with refresh tokens.

My idea is that the JWT would be issued at login time and would only include the user ID. It would be sent in an `HttpOnly`, `SameSite=Strict`, and `Secure` cookie. On logout, the cookie storing it could be overridden by the backend. Additionally, to avoid keeping cookies around when a user does not log out, they could have a `MaxAge` attribute.

Is it plausible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The most fundamental rule of web application security is **you can not trust the client**.

The expiry date is the single most important security feature of a JWT, because it's the only way you can tell the difference between an old stolen token and a newly created one.

A JWT with no expiry is like a skeleton key: if anyone gets hold of it, they can carry on logging in as that user, forever. Sure, if the browser obeys all your restrictions, and deletes it as soon as you tell it to, the skeleton key won't leak anywhere. But why create the skeleton key in the first place, when it's trivial to avoid?

You mention adding a max-age to the cookie, so you already have an idea of what a reasonable session lifetime would be; use that as the expiry date in your JWT.